# OP in comments doesn't have the blue background

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, stack-overflow-app

So as stated in the title in comments the OP doesn't have a blue background that highlights from regular users like exists in site.

[image]

Comment: As per your screenshot it seems the entire comments section has a grey background whereas on the main site it is white. Even if the blue background of the name was there, it would probably not stand out at all. Might be status-by-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the report. This bug has been fixed as of version 1.0.1, going live now.

Comment: I just confirmed it is fixed!